# PHP MongoClient (PECL) and exact word full text search

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, pecl

I've created a full text search index with different weights and it's working good for the "OR" basic search when you do a basic query like below:

```
db.items.find( { $text: { $search: "iphone 5" }}, {score: {$meta: "textScore"}}).pretty()
```

This query (shell client side) will find all items that contains words "iphone" **OR** "5". In PHP we make this query like this:

```
$product = 'iphone 5';
$search = array( '$text' => array('$search' => $product) );
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:xxxxx", array("username" => 'xxxxx', "password" => 'xxxxx', "db" => 'xxxxx'));
$db = $m->mybase;
$collection = $db->items;
$cursor = $collection->find( $search, array('score' => array('$meta' => 'textScore') ) )->sort( array('score' => array('$meta' => 'textScore') ) );
```

---

My problem is concerning the "AND" operator in full text search in PHP. In shell client side in order to get all items that contains words "iphone" **AND** "5" I do as below:

```
db.items.find( { $text: { $search: "\"iphone\" \"5\"" }}, {score: {$meta: "textScore"}}).pretty()
```

It's working perfectly but in PHP I tried many ways to get the same results but it's not working at all, what I've tried:

```
$product = '\"iphone\" \"5\"';
$product = '\\"iphone\\" \\"5\\"';
$product = "\'iphone\' \'5\'";
...
```

How to do it in PHP so I could have the same result as shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a meal I remembered that simple quote is not acting the same as double quote for special chars such as "\" so I simply changed to that working code:

```
$product = "\"iphone\" \"5\"";
```

It's working as a charm, hope it would help someone someday ;)